# 2 SQL query with Union Building

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have 2 SQL query, i want to make both in one SQL query and get all the elements from each query only in one row.

I want to have 6 columns for the result("kunde", "GesamtdateiGrosse", "anzahlObjGesamt", "GesamtdateiGrossefertig", "anzahlObjFertig" "RestGross") and 2 lines. RestGross would then be the difference between GesamtdateiGrosse and GesamtdateiGrossefertig

```
SELECT 
    kunde.nummer AS kunde, 
    SUM(datei.groesse) as "GesamtdateiGrosse",
    COUNT (DISTINCT objekt.id) as anzahlObjGesamt
FROM datei 
INNER JOIN  objekt ON datei.id_objekt = objekt.id 
INNER JOIN auftrag ON objekt.id_auftrag = auftrag.id 
INNER JOIN kunde ON auftrag.id_kunde = kunde.id 
WHERE kunde.nummer = 777
GROUP BY kunde.nummer

UNION

SELECT 
    kunde.nummer AS kunde, 
    SUM(datei.groesse) as "GesamtdateiGrossefertig",
    COUNT (DISTINCT objekt.id) as anzahlObjFertig
FROM datei 
INNER JOIN objekt ON datei.id_objekt = objekt.id 
INNER JOIN auftrag ON objekt.id_auftrag = auftrag.id 
INNER JOIN status ON objekt.id_restorestatus = status.id
INNER JOIN kunde ON auftrag.id_kunde = kunde.id 
WHERE status.name = 'fertig' AND kunde.nummer = 777
GROUP BY kunde.nummer
```

I expect the output 3 rown 3 column (Kunde, "GesamtdateiGrosse",anzahlObjGesamt)

Comment: Please share your input/output?

Comment: So what does this query return? It's hard to help you when you don't provide sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you close to what you want. The idea is to add another join in the first to bring in the `status` table, and the do *conditional* aggregation.

This requires that there is a 1:1 relationship between `objekt` and `status` (meaning that, for a given record in `objekt`, there is always one and only one record in `status` that satisfies condition `objekt.id_restorestatus = status.id`).

Consider:

```
SELECT
    kunde.nummer AS kunde, 
    SUM(datei.groesse) as "GesamtdateiGrosse",
    COUNT(DISTINCT objekt.id) as anzahlObjGesamt,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status.name = 'fertig' THEN datei.groesse ELSE 0 END) as "GesamtdateiGrossefertig",
    COUNT (DISTINCT (CASE WHEN status.name = 'fertig' THEN objekt.id END)) as anzahlObjFertig
FROM datei 
INNER JOIN objekt ON datei.id_objekt = objekt.id 
INNER JOIN auftrag ON objekt.id_auftrag = auftrag.id 
INNER JOIN kunde ON auftrag.id_kunde = kunde.id 
INNER JOIN status ON objekt.id_restorestatus = status.id
WHERE kunde.nummer = 777
GROUP BY kunde.nummer
```

Comment: Okay. 
Thank you, sir. 

how can I insert the column RestGross is of the query?

RestGroesse = column GesamtdateiGrosse - column GesamtdateiGrossefertig

Thank you.

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN status.name <> 'fertig' THEN datei.groesse ELSE 0.0 END) as RestGroesse,